# How to show 'square' character in itext

Tags: itext

I am using itext 7  to create pdf report. I found it can't show 'square' character correctly. For example: m/s²

It always throws the Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.getCidFontType2(PdfType0Font.java:723)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.flushFontData(PdfType0Font.java:811)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfType0Font.flush(PdfType0Font.java:600)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushFonts(PdfDocument.java:1846)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:800)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:120)
```

I have tried to some examples what I searched on google. like:
https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/showing-special-characters

The following is the code:

```
    File baseFontFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("font/FreeSans.ttf").getPath());

    PdfFont baseFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(baseFontFile.getAbsolutePath(), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

Text unitTxt = null；        
if("m/s²".equals(unit)) { 
    unitTxt = new Text(unit); 
    unitTxt .setFont(baseFont );
    unitTxt .setFontSize(11);

    }
```

The above code will not throw exception, but it will finally throw exception when PdfDocument.close

Comment: You declare and initialize a `baseFontFile` variable but later access a `baseFont` variable. It is completely unclear how they relate if at all.

Comment: @MKL  hi, sorry , I missed some code in example, I have edited it.

Comment: I would propose you try not using the resource via a path `String` (as returned by `baseFontFile.getAbsolutePath()`)  as this string might not denote a regular file in the file system as expected by `PdfFontFactory.createFont(String, String)` but e.g. an entry in a JAR or WAR archive. Instead of `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` use `...getResourceAsStream` and `StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray` to get the font as a `byte[]` and then use `PdfFontFactory.createFont(byte[], String)`.

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: @mkl hi mkl, I followed your instruction and tried. But it nothing changed.  I get same error.

Comment: InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("font/FreeSans.ttf"); 
 
PdfFont sysFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(this.toByteArray(inputStream),PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, false);

Comment: I believe program has indeed found out font file. But the 'm/s²' character need some special way to handle